# How to indicate to a specific version of database? [Django] [PostgreSQL]

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I using django version 3.0.2.
I'd like to use postgreSQL as my instance db.

And there are two version postgreSQL in server.

[image]

After config setting.py DATABASES parameter, and runserver.
It showed error.

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'dj_web_console',
        'USER': 'django',
        'PASSWORD': 'django',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

`psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "django"`

I'm sure that the username and password are correct.

How to config pg_path in Django as odoo:

[image]

In this case, I can use the specific version of pgsql. And run smoothly.

Comment: Django isn't starting Postgres. You should be starting the Postgres server yourself, at which point you can decide what version to start.

Comment: How and where to set it? I can understand what you say. In my case, I have a "9.6" version of pg with db named "A", the other version is 12 with db named "B", If I set the DATABASE parameter to A (version "9.6"), It can run!! But I can not set it to B. It will cause an error.

Comment: How are you starting your database server…‽

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this by indicating the port of the version I installed.
In this case, I have a version 9.6 which install in 5432 and the other is 5433.
So I just solved this by filling in 5433.

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'dj_web_console',
        'USER': 'django',
        'PASSWORD': 'django',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5433',
    }
}
```